# Access Database Total Field not calculates empty records?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

My Query Result is as below 
[image]

Query:

```
SELECT reservations.customerid, 
 (SELECT SUM(balances.balance) FROM balances 
  WHERE balances.customer_id = reservations.customerid) 
                               AS Preveious_balance ,
 (SELECT SUM(services.Amount_due) 
   FROM services 
   WHERE services.customer_id = reservations.customerid 
     AND services.status=0) AS Service_due ,  
(SELECT SUM(foods.Amount_due) 
    FROM foods WHERE foods.customer_id = reservations.customerid 
    AND foods.status=0) AS Food_due,
((due_nights.Due_nights - reservations.billed_nights) * rooms.rate) 
  as Accomendation,
(Preveious_balance + Service_due  +  Food_due + Accomendation) 
    AS Total_due 

FROM reservations, due_nights, rooms 
  WHERE reservations.customerid = due_nights.customerid 
 AND reservations.roomno = rooms.roomno
```

Total_due is Empty if some other columns value gets empty so how to fix this ?

Comment: try nz(SUM(balances.balance),0) AND CHECK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT reservations.customerid, 
     (SELECT SUM (balances.balance)
         FROM balances WHERE balances.customer_id = reservations.customerid)
           AS Preveious_balance ,
     (SELECT SUM(services.Amount_due)
            FROM services WHERE services.customer_id = reservations.customerid 
             AND services.status=0) AS Service_due ,  
    (SELECT SUM(foods.Amount_due)
            FROM foods WHERE foods.customer_id = reservations.customerid 
           AND foods.status=0) AS Food_due,
    ((due_nights.Due_nights - reservations.billed_nights) * rooms.rate)
          as Accomendation,
    (NZ(Preveious_balance,0) + NZ(Service_due,0)  +  NZ(Food_due,0) + NZ(Accomendation,0)) AS Total_due 
  FROM reservations, due_nights, rooms 
WHERE reservations.customerid = due_nights.customerid 
AND reservations.roomno = rooms.roomno
```

You can you `NZ function of Access` to check whether the sum is null.If so assign 0. It will solve your issue

If not **access**

```
SELECT reservations.customerid, 
 (SELECT IIf(Sum(balances.balance) Is Null, 0, Sum(balances.balance))
     FROM balances WHERE balances.customer_id = reservations.customerid)
       AS Preveious_balance ,
 (SELECT IIf(Sum(services.Amount_due) Is Null, 0, Sum(services.Amount_due))
        FROM services WHERE services.customer_id = reservations.customerid 
         AND services.status=0) AS Service_due ,  

 (SELECT IIf(Sum(foods.Amount_due) Is Null, 0, Sum(foods.Amount_due))
        FROM foods WHERE foods.customer_id = reservations.customerid 
       AND foods.status=0) AS Food_due,
((due_nights.Due_nights - reservations.billed_nights) * rooms.rate)
      as Accomendation,
(Preveious_balance + Service_due  +  Food_due + Accomendation) AS Total_due 
   FROM reservations, due_nights, rooms 
 WHERE reservations.customerid = due_nights.customerid 
 AND reservations.roomno = rooms.roomno
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT reservations.customerid, 
 (SELECT IIf(Sum(balances.balance) Is Null, 0, Sum(balances.balance))
     FROM balances WHERE balances.customer_id = reservations.customerid)
       AS Preveious_balance ,
 (SELECT IIf(Sum(services.Amount_due) Is Null, 0, Sum(services.Amount_due))
        FROM services WHERE services.customer_id = reservations.customerid 
         AND services.status=0) AS Service_due ,  

 (SELECT IIf(Sum(foods.Amount_due) Is Null, 0, Sum(foods.Amount_due))
        FROM foods WHERE foods.customer_id = reservations.customerid 
       AND foods.status=0) AS Food_due,
((due_nights.Due_nights - reservations.billed_nights) * rooms.rate)
      as Accomendation,
(Preveious_balance + Service_due  +  Food_due + Accomendation) AS Total_due 
   FROM reservations, due_nights, rooms 
 WHERE reservations.customerid = due_nights.customerid 
 AND reservations.roomno = rooms.roomno
```

if you are using ADO.NET or other programing to check null values this is correct becouse Nz is only available in MS access.